# Minmax and Maxmin of $F(x, y)=(x-y)^2$

Tags: calculus

Let $F(x, y)=(x-y)^2$. Find $\max_{0\leq x\leq 1} \min_{0\leq y\leq 1} F(x, y)$ and $\min_{0\leq y\leq 1} \max_{0\leq x\leq 1} F(x, y)$.

I guess $\max_{0\leq x\leq 1} \min_{0\leq y\leq 1} F(x, y) = 0$, since when $y=x$ $F(x, y)$ gets $\min$ which is $0$, and $\max(0)=0$.

The solution says $\min_{0\leq y\leq 1} \max_{0\leq x\leq 1} F(x, y)=\frac 1 4$ but I don't know how to get it. Any help, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For fixed $y$ the function $x \mapsto (x-y)^{2}$ is decreasing on $[0,y]$ and increasing on $[y,1]$. Hence its maximum  value is attained at either $0$ or $1$. The maximum value is $y^{2}$ or $(1-y)^{2}$, whichever is higher. It is $y^{2}$ if $y >\frac  1 2$ and $(1-y)^{2}$ if $y \leq \frac  1 2$. I will let you handle  the rest.